# context has no effect on the authentication with graphql and apollo-server

Tags: express, authentication, graphql, apollo-server

I need to implement Authentication system, i have done the below code, but doesn't work, login and signup Mutations are working correctly and i have received the token, but when i try to make a query to the users, i can do that either i add authorization header or not, its looks like no real connection between contex in index.js and the context in resolvers?

i have this in index.js:

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import express from 'express';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { dbConnect } from './db_connect.js';
import { syncDB } from './db_schema.js';
import { typeDefs } from './schema.js';
import { resolvers } from './resolver.js';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { context } from './context.js'

dbConnect();

const app = express();

// Setup http server
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Setup apollo server
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: context,
    plugins: [
        ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
    ],
});

await server.start();

app.use(
    '/graphql',
    cors(),
    bodyParser.json(),
    expressMiddleware(server)
);


httpServer.listen(2000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at http://localhost:2000/graphql');
});
```

and here is (context.js):

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';


const secretKey = 'OSAMAHASH';
export const context = ({ req }) => {

    const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
    console.log('Authorization token:', token);
    if (!token) {
        throw new GraphQLError('User is not authenticated', {
            extensions: {
                code: 'UNAUTHENTICATED',
                http: { status: 401 },
            },
        });
    }

    try {

        const user = jwt.verify(token, secretKey);
        return { user };
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Invalid or expired token');
    }
}
```

and in resolvers.js:

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: async(_, __, context) => {
            try {
                console.log(context)
                const allUsers = await User.findAll();
                return allUsers;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message)
            }
        }
},
```

Comment: Are you using Apollo-Server v3 or v4? The pattern is different between the two. Here's a [v4 example](https://github.com/MichelFloyd/auth-demo).